# C# Inserting DataGridView data into database succeeds but only returns the first value n times?

Tags: c#, sql, datagridview, oledb

Any idea why this only returns the first value of the DataGridView 5 times given a DGV of 5 rows?
The sql should insert successfully, there must be something wrong in my loop that i'm not picking up. Ideally it should return the 5 rows of values in the datagridview not just the first, effectively transferring the entire datagridview into the database.

```
using (OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(Con))
using (OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand())
{
    cmd.Connection = conn;
    conn.Open();
    for (int i = 0; i <= DGVExcel.Rows.Count - 1; i++)
    {
        cmd.CommandText =
            "Insert INTO ACTB (FirstName, LastName, GrossIncome, LessTNT, TaxableIncomeCE, TaxableIncomePE, GrossTaxableIncome, LessTE, LessPPH, NetTax, TaxDue, HeldTaxCE, HeldTaxPE, TotalTax) " +
            "VALUES(@First, @Last, @Gross, @LessTNT, @TCI, @ADDTI, @GTI, @LessTE, @LessPPH, @LessNTI, @TD, @TWCE, @TWPE, @TATW)";
        //cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID", Convert.ToInt32(txtID.Text));
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@First", DGVExcel.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Last", DGVExcel.Rows[i].Cells[1].Value);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Gross", Convert.ToDouble(DGVExcel.Rows[i].Cells[2].Value));
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@LessTNT",
            Convert.ToDouble(DGVExcel.Rows[i].Cells[3].Value));
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TCI", Convert.ToDouble(DGVExcel.Rows[i].Cells[4].Value));
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ADDTI", Convert.ToDouble(DGVExcel.Rows[i].Cells[5].Value));
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@GTI", Convert.ToDouble(DGVExcel.Rows[i].Cells[6].Value));
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@LessTE", Convert.ToDouble(DGVExcel.Rows[i].Cells[7].Value));
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@LessPPH",
            Convert.ToDouble(DGVExcel.Rows[i].Cells[8].Value));
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@LessNTI",
            Convert.ToDouble(DGVExcel.Rows[i].Cells[9].Value));
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TD", Convert.ToDouble(DGVExcel.Rows[i].Cells[10].Value));
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TWCE", Convert.ToDouble(DGVExcel.Rows[i].Cells[11].Value));
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TWPE", Convert.ToDouble(DGVExcel.Rows[i].Cells[12].Value));
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TATW", Convert.ToDouble(DGVExcel.Rows[i].Cells[13].Value));
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
}
```

Comment: Use debug and see this is looking okay on first look.

Comment: Right. I've already debugged it and it runs fine. Except for the fact that it returns only the first value of the DataGridView n times. N being the number of items of the View. My guess is it's probably the parameter not getting updated somewhere after the first pass.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to initialize your OleDdCommand for every new insert call during the loop. Try this:

```
using (OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(Con))
{
    conn.Open();
    for (int i = 0; i <= DGVExcel.Rows.Count - 1; i++)
    {
        OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand();
        cmd.Connection = conn;

        cmd.CommandText =
            "Insert INTO ACTB (FirstName, LastName, GrossIncome, LessTNT, TaxableIncomeCE, TaxableIncomePE, GrossTaxableIncome, LessTE, LessPPH, NetTax, TaxDue, HeldTaxCE, HeldTaxPE, TotalTax) " +
            "VALUES(@First, @Last, @Gross, @LessTNT, @TCI, @ADDTI, @GTI, @LessTE, @LessPPH, @LessNTI, @TD, @TWCE, @TWPE, @TATW)";
        //cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID", Convert.ToInt32(txtID.Text));
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@First", DGVExcel.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Last", DGVExcel.Rows[i].Cells[1].Value);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Gross", Convert.ToDouble(DGVExcel.Rows[i].Cells[2].Value));
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@LessTNT",
            Convert.ToDouble(DGVExcel.Rows[i].Cells[3].Value));
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TCI", Convert.ToDouble(DGVExcel.Rows[i].Cells[4].Value));
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ADDTI", Convert.ToDouble(DGVExcel.Rows[i].Cells[5].Value));
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@GTI", Convert.ToDouble(DGVExcel.Rows[i].Cells[6].Value));
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@LessTE", Convert.ToDouble(DGVExcel.Rows[i].Cells[7].Value));
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@LessPPH",
            Convert.ToDouble(DGVExcel.Rows[i].Cells[8].Value));
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@LessNTI",
            Convert.ToDouble(DGVExcel.Rows[i].Cells[9].Value));
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TD", Convert.ToDouble(DGVExcel.Rows[i].Cells[10].Value));
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TWCE", Convert.ToDouble(DGVExcel.Rows[i].Cells[11].Value));
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TWPE", Convert.ToDouble(DGVExcel.Rows[i].Cells[12].Value));
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TATW", Convert.ToDouble(DGVExcel.Rows[i].Cells[13].Value));
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
}
```

Comment: Or, just add the parameters once (before the loop), and then inside the loop only set their values. Doing it this way would seem more efficient to me.

Comment: I'm gonna try this now. Btw @stakx is there like a shortcut for reducing the indentations or must it be done manually? I'm thinking of making a post on VS asking for the same thing along with other quality of life tips. EDIT: I got it to work. I also tried cmd.parameters.Clear(), is this acceptable or must I change it with your suggestion?

Comment: @Vendredi: No need to completely remove and re-add all parameters. Just create them and the command once before the loop, then repeatedly set their values (think `cmd.Parameters["@param"].Value = newValue`). You can also store each parameter object in a variable to get rid of the repeated `cmd.Parameters[...]` lookup: `var param = new SqlDataParameter("@param", SqlDbType....); cmd.Parameters.Add(param); ... param.Value = ...;` These examples are for SQL Server but it should work very similarly for the OLE DB provider.

Comment: @Vendredi, the solution which stakx has suggested (which is to re-set only param values with each loop iteration instead of the whole command) is also good. I just wanted to create the simplest version with minimal code changes which would be easy to understand.

Comment: @stakx, and andrews But what's the trade-off? I understand either of them could work, but one is visibly more verbose.

Comment: @Vendredi: My suggestion is mostly an optimization. If your code runs sufficiently efficient, then you might not have to optimize at all. It's still a good idea, either way.